# c++, levmar optimization, lapack, tnt library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization, lapack++

it would be kind of someone to help with the issue:

i recently came across a levmar optimization code from  http://www.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/levmar/

the library uses lapack.

i could not find lapack that works properly with c++ visual studio 2010 express edition.

instead i found the TNT library from 
http://math.nist.gov/tnt/download.html

my question is does anyone know if the tnt can substitute the lapack routines used in levmar.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation only I opted for Intel's Math Kernel Library (MKL). Just download the trial version from Intel's website. Although the program's trial only lasts 30 days the MKL library files will still be usable. You can link your project to the "mkl_rt.lib" file and you're all set.